# Multiplication in R without using the multiplication sign

Tags: r

I like solving my math problems(high school) using R as it is faster than writing on a piece of paper. One problem I'm having is that I have to keep writing the multiplication sign, example:

9x^2 + 24x + 16 yields = Error: unexpected symbol in "9x"

Is there any way in R to multiply 4x, without having to write 4*x but only 4x?
Would save me some time in having to write one extra character the whole time! Thanks

Comment: You're also writing `+` signs and hitting the space bar.  Why does  `*` bother you?

Comment: I feel that I'm writing more *'s then +'s, it would save me some time, the problem also looks clearer in the console without all the *'s, is there some other program I could use?

Comment: I wouldn't think so because how things are written in mathematics differ from how things are written in code.  You usually have to explicitly tell a programming language exactly what you are doing at each operation

Comment: Not R, but what about something like this: [Mathics](http://www.mathics.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Having a number in front of a character without any space simply isn't valid syntax in R.

Comment: Can't I write some sort of function which will turn x into = *(9) so when I write 4x it will equal to 4*(9) ?

Comment: No. The R parser will not parse that. It's invalid syntax. You can't fix a syntax error with a function definition.

Comment: Or I guess you could write your own parser if you want to enter your functions as strings. Something like `myparse<-function(x) {eval(parse(text=gsub("\\b(\\d+)([[:alpha:]]\\w*)\\b", "\\1*\\2", x)), parent.frame())}; x<-5; myparse("9x^2 + 24x + 16")` but that's just getting silly.

Comment: ok, I don't know if this could work. But is it possible, for example if I write `"9x^2 + 24x + 16"` in the console, and the `"Error: unexpected symbol in "9x"` shows up, instead of sending the error could you tell R to use `myparse("9x^2 + 24x + 16")` instead? That would solve it. @MrFlick

Comment: @Johnsy22 yes, you could, and then you could write some more parsers, and pretty soon you've developed your very own language.   Probably not a good thing overall.

Answer (score 0):

Take a step back and look at the syntax rules for, say,  Excel, Matlab, Python,  Mathematica.  Every language has its rules, generally (:-) ) with good reason.  For example, in `R`,  the following are legal object names:

`foo`
`foo.bar`
`foo1`
`foo39`

But `39foo` is not legal.  So if you wanted any sequence `[0-9][Letters]` or the reverse to indicate multiplication, you'd have a conflict with naming rules.